# Call Functions on User Control Inside Wizard Step

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have several user controls which inherit from the following abstract class:

```
Public MustInherit Class CustomVRAUserControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public MustOverride Sub ClearErrors()
    Public MustOverride Sub UpdateLabels()
    Public MustOverride Function Validate() As Boolean
    Public MustOverride Sub UpdateSession()

End Class
```

I have a wizard which uses the user controls.  There is some dynamic work removing steps for certain conditions.  Here's a sample of the wizard:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="VRAWizard" runat="server"......>    
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:WizardStep ID="wizResidentialAddress" runat="server" 
                Title="RESIDENTIAL ADDRESS" StepType="Step">
                  <uc2:ResidentialAddress ID="uctlResidentialAddress" runat="server" />                       
            </asp:WizardStep>

            <asp:WizardStep ID="wizMailingAddress" runat="server" 
                Title="MAILING ADDRESS"  StepType="Step">
                  <uc3:MailingAddress ID="uctlMailingAddress" runat="server" /> 
            </asp:WizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:Wizard>
```

In the code behind of my wizard class, I have some work on the NextButton click:

```
Protected Sub VRAWizard_NextButtonClick(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles VRAWizard.NextButtonClick

        If VRAWizard.ActiveStep.ID = "wizResidentialAddress" Then
            uctlResidentialAddress.ClearErrors()
            If Not (uctlResidentialAddress.validate) Then
                uctlResidentialAddress.UpdateLabels()
                e.Cancel = True
            Else
                uctlResidentialAddress.UpdateSession()
            End If
        End If


        If VRAWizard.ActiveStep.ID = "wizMailingAddress" Then
            uctlMailingAddress.ClearErrors()
            If Not (uctlMailingAddress.validate) Then
                uctlMailingAddress.updateLabels()
                e.Cancel = True
            Else
                uctlMailingAddress.UpdateSession()
            End If
        End If
```

Obviously, that's pretty repetitive.

I'd like to do something like ....

```
CType(VRAWizard.ActiveStep.Controls.Item(0), CustomVRAUserControl).ClearErrors()

    If Not (CType(VRAWizard.ActiveStep.Controls.Item(0), CustomVRAUserControl).Validate()) Then
        CType(VRAWizard.ActiveStep.Controls.Item(0), CustomVRAUserControl).UpdateLabels()
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        CType(VRAWizard.ActiveStep.Controls.Item(0), CustomVRAUserControl).UpdateSession()
    End If
```

But of course, doing that generates a runtime error because the compiler is unable to make the cast.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be able to handle the cast.  I think the first control in the collection is a literal, so you'll have to do this:

```
CType(VRAWizard.ActiveStep.Controls.Item(1), CustomVRAUserControl).ClearErrors()
```

Since you're using it again, you might as well set it to a variable:

```
Dim objVRAControl As CustomVRAUserControl = CType(VRAWizard.ActiveStep.Controls.Item(1), CustomVRAUserControl)
```

Then you can do:

```
objVRAControl.ClearErrors()
```

If that doesn't work, use a BreakPoint and a Watch variable to make sure you're using the right index.

Comment: thank you!  Changing to use the second control worked perfectly.